# Capturing a screenshot

Tags: ruby, webdriver, watir

I'm unable to figure out how to capture a screenshot when a test fails in watir. Please any help/examples?

Here is an exaample of my code

```
testName =  "Entered 000000 - Invalid Unit Number"    
browser.text_field(:name => 'unitNumber').set '000000'
browser.button(:name => "OpRetrieve").click
message=browser.text_field(:id => 'messages').text
if message == "Invalid Unit Number"
  f1.puts "PASSED #" + testId.to_s + ": " + testName
else
   f1.puts "FAILED #" + testId.to_s + ": " + testName + ". Message: " + message
   "Capturd screenshot"
end
testId=testId+1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do it:

```
browser.screenshot.save 'screenshot.png'
```

For more information see http://watir.github.io/docs/screenshots/

Comment: Hi I tried it but I am getting an error message "in `<top (required)>': undefined method `screenshot' for #<Watir::IE:0x1581d20> (NoMethodError)". Sorry its the first time i am trying to use it.

Comment: Based on your exception, it looks like you are using watir-classic (not watir-webdriver). What version are you using? The screenshot api was added in 3.1.0.

Comment: ruby 1.9.3p0 (2011-10-30) [i386-mingw32] and gem 1.8.18 how do i check if the screenshot api was added? How can i add it?

Comment: I did Thanks gem install watir watir-classic
and its working fine now thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

This works for phantomjs, I guess it should work for any driver.

```
browser.driver.screenshot.save 'wtf.png'
```

[Here's a working example I made before.](https://github.com/nurettin/capybara_poltergeist_phantomjs_test/blob/master/capybara_poltergeist_phantomjs_test.rb) It does something like:

```
page.driver.render 'test.pdf'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve like this also.

```
 File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);  
 FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File("C:\\screenShot1.png"));
```

for using these you need to import below classes

```
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.openqa.selenium.TakesScreenshot;
```